# Uploadify doesn't send filename

Tags: java, uploadify, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm trying to use Uploadify for uploading multiple files,

```
$('#fileuploadinput').uploadify({
    uploader: '/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    script: '/uploadpath',
    cancelImg: '/js/uploadify/cancel.png',
    multi: true,
    fileDataName: 'uploadFile'
});
```

and there is a Spring controller with comons-fileupload 1.2.1 on the server side.

```
for (org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem item : items) {
    String name = item.getName();
    // some other stuff
}
```

I need to get the original name of the uploaded file, and it's fine when using standard input tag - the name is where it should be and item.getName() just returns it as expected. However, when using Uploadify item.getName() returns null. Is there a way to get the name?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spring MVC,  they provide a wrapper class, org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

you can use method, getOriginalFilename() to get the file name.

more information can be found from http://www.ke-cai.net/2010/12/file-upload-with-uplodify-and-spring.html

@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String processUpload(@RequestParam MultipartFile file,
                ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

```
        log.debug("========= upload file:" + file.getOriginalFilename());
}
```